# on Blur of input field not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

so here is my problem, i have a input field i i know its kind of simple but i am just stuck with it:

```
<input type="text"  onfocus="value=''" onblur="value='Enter your email address'" name="emailAddress" value="Enter your email address">
```

now what it does, when i click in, input field is ready to take input, when i enter some thing and focus/click out, my data **disappears** and ***enter your email address*** from onblur comes in, so any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<input type="text"  onfocus="value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter your email address'" name="emailAddress" value="Enter your email address">
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/GdPJa/

`onblur` check if the value is empty, if it's return the default value, otherwise it doesn't do anything.